# cannot call .next on Observables

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subject-observer

I am sharing data across two sibling components using an injectible. In my injectible I am using an observable like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DatasService { 
    message: Observable<string> = new Observable<string>();
    changeMessage(){
        this.message.next('Arpita'); //Property next doesn't exist
    }

    changeMessage2(){
        this.message.next('Ankan');
    }
}
```

But then when I am using Subject in place of Observable it works fine. I want to use Observable instead of Subject, so is it possible?
I am new to reactive programming, and I am confused.

Comment: *"I want to use Observable instead of Subject"* - why?!

Comment: @jonrsharpe great catch i get it why i get the dv now

Comment: Because when I am using Subject I cannot set a default value. I know, I can use BehaviorSubject for that, but since am new to reactive, I want to stick to observables for the time being

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any work around for this without using Subject

Comment: So you want to use an observable because you can't set a default value for a subject, except that you already know that you *can* create a subject with a default value? Your question is very confusing: if you could use an observable as a subject *why would the subject exist*?

Comment: Ok, so I get it there's no work around and I have to use Subject or BehaviorSubject to use next(). Thanks I just wanted to know whether it was possible.

Answer (score -3):

use a global variable instead of injectible. so that you can access them through out your project. 
1.create a property in DTO. 
2.import in that component where you want to use. 
3.create a variable of that type in constructor's parameter. 
4.access with the use of that variable.